# SQL select query to display name from another table in two seperate columns

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Scenario is I have a list of fixtures as below.Fixtures are represented by team ids

**Fixture Table**

```
FixtureID    HomeTeam   AwayTeam
1            1          2
2            2          4
```

I need to then look to the Team table to grab the name of each team

**Team Table**

```
TeamID  TeamName
1       Team1
2       Team2
```

I need to run a query which will grab the fixtures and change the TeamID's into the team name so it looks like

```
HomeTeam TeamName AwayTeam TeamName
 1       Team1    2         Team2
 2       Team2    4         Team4
```

At the moment I have

```
SELECT  Fixtures.HomeTeam, Teams.TeamName, Fixtures.AwayTeam
FROM Fixtures INNER JOIN
Teams ON Fixtures.HomeTeam = Teams.TeamID
```

**Which outputs:**

```
HomeTeam TeamName             AwayTeam
1        Donegal Celtic       2
2        Banbridge Town       1
3        Limavdy United       5
```

I am just having trouble getting the away team name to show.Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need two joins:

```
SELECT f.HomeTeam, th.TeamName, f.AwayTeam, ta.TeamName
FROM Fixtures f INNER JOIN
     Teams th
     ON f.HomeTeam = th.TeamID INNER JOIN
     Teams ta
     ON f.AwayTeam = ta.TeamId;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `join` Team table twice, e.g.:

```
SELECT f.FixtureID, t1.TeamID, t1.name, t2.TeamID, t2.name
FROM fixtures f JOIN team t1 ON f.hometeam = t1.TeamID
JOIN team t2 on f.awayteam = t2.TeamID;
```

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0c41b/1/0)**.

Answer (score 1):

Join `Teams` table twice with `Fixtures` table.

```
SELECT Fixtures.HomeTeam, t1.TeamName, Fixtures.AwayTeam, t2.TeamName
FROM Fixtures INNER JOIN
Teams t1
ON Fixtures.HomeTeam = t1.TeamID 
INNER JOIN
Teams t2
ON Fixtures.AwayTeam = t2.TeamId;
```

[Working](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7afbce/1/0) sample.